# How do I conditionally iterate in reverse?

Tags: rust, iterator

I want to switch the direction of an iterator based on a boolean parameter. I tried the following approach, but it ends with a compile error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let numbers = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    print(&numbers, false);
    print(&numbers, true);
}

fn print(what: &[i32], reverse: bool) {
    let iter = what.iter();

    if reverse {
        iter = iter.rev();
    }

    for n in iter {
        println!("{n}");
    }
}
```

This is the error I receive:

```
// Error:
mismatched types
expected struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, _>`
   found struct `Rev<std::slice::Iter<'_, _>>`
```

How could I implement my desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using dynamic dispatch as explained [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/iterate-over-iterator-or-rev/51866/2) like so:

```rust
fn iterateMyData(a: &mut VecDeque<A>, b: &mut BTreeMap<u64, VecDeque<B>>) {
    // Do something.

    let reverse: bool = a.front().unwrap().reverse;

    for a_value in a.iter_mut() {
        let mut temp_iter1;
        let mut temp_iter2;
        let mut iter: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = _> = if reverse {
            temp_iter1 = b.values_mut().rev();
            &mut temp_iter1
        } else {
            temp_iter2 = b.values_mut();
            &mut temp_iter2
        };
        
        for b_vec in iter {
            // Do something.
        }
    }
}
```

and the [rustexplorer link](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0A%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3Acollections%3A%3A%7BBTreeMap%2C%20VecDeque%7D%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Something%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20reverse%3A%20bool%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20Something%3B%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20u64%3B%0A%0Afn%20iterateMyData(a%3A%20%26mut%20VecDeque%3CA%3E%2C%20b%3A%20%26mut%20BTreeMap%3Cu64%2C%20VecDeque%3CB%3E%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Do%20something.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20reverse%3A%20bool%20%3D%20a.front().unwrap().reverse%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20a_value%20in%20a.iter_mut()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20temp_iter1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20temp_iter2%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20iter%3A%20%26mut%20dyn%20Iterator%3CItem%20%3D%20_%3E%20%3D%20if%20reverse%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20temp_iter1%20%3D%20b.values_mut().rev()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26mut%20temp_iter1%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20temp_iter2%20%3D%20b.values_mut()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26mut%20temp_iter2%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20b_vec%20in%20iter%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Do%20something.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A).

However as already noted in the [linked thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/iterate-over-iterator-or-rev/51866/1) above, it is probably easier and better to use an enum (crate) like [either](https://crates.io/crates/either) like so

```rust
let mut iter =
    if reverse { 
        Either::Left(b.values_mut().rev()) 
    }
    else { 
        Either::Right(b.values_mut()) 
    };
```

Also in the case that you **just need to print** out the iterator in a certain direction based on a flag this can be done without external crates as follows:

```rust
fn main() {

    let numbers = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    print(&numbers, false);
    print(&numbers, true);
        
}

fn print(what: &[i32], reverse: bool) {
    //match statement condition check
    match reverse {
        true => {
            for n in what.iter().rev() {
                println!("{n}");
            }
        },
        false => {
            for n in what.iter() {
                println!("{n}");
            }
            
        },
    }
}
```